# SQL Server: Select minimum between two values in a SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, min

I'd appreciate if someone could help me with this SQL statement. I currently have this:

```
select sum(datediff(second, [date1], [date2])) from [MyTable] where <condition>
```

But I need to refine this selection, i.e. if the difference between dates is greater than @MaxDiffSecs then the @MaxDiffSecs should be used for summation instead. I tried looking into the MIN operator but it has only one parameter, where I'd expect at least 2 to get the minimum of.

Well, anyway, thanks in advance. (I guess you can tell that I'm not really efficient at SQL :)

Comment: Have you looked at the CASE statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(second, [date1], [date2]) > @MaxDiffSecs THEN @MaxDiffSecs
    ELSE DATEDIFF(second, [date1], [date2]) END)
FROM [MyTable] 
WHERE <condition>
```

This is off the top of my head, not sure if the CASE works inside a `SUM`

If that syntax does not work you could use a CTE

```
WITH ValuesToSum AS (
    SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(second, [date1], [date2]) > @MaxDiffSecs THEN @MaxDiffSecs
        ELSE DATEDIFF(second, [date1], [date2]) END AS TheValue
    FROM [MyTable]
    WHERE <condition>
)

SELECT SUM(TheValue) FROM ValuesToSum
```

Comment: Thanks. You see my real example has quite complex CASE WHEN statements instead [date1] and [date2] parts in my sample here. So doing it like you showed will technically run them twice. Is there any way to do the DATEDIFF once, store the result in a variable and then check if it's greater than @MaxDiffSecs for the SUM operator?

Comment: @ahmd0 - It's difficult to avoid performing the calculation twice in this instance. You may be better off storing the result of your complex `CASE` statements to avoid having to recalculate it again and again but that may not work if the values used in the calculation change frequently, necessitating multiple updates. Without knowing your actual table definition and `CASE` statements it's hard to say which approach is better.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. You can see the full SQL statement that is being generated by an ASP NET script here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31368633/sql_query_001.txt
As you can see it's not just a tiny one like I gave here, although most of it is just a somewhat repeating part. So any idea how to optimize that?

Comment: There are a few things in that query which would cause it to be slow and some other things I need you to explain. You are using `ISDATE` on the fields `[inTime]` and `[outTime]`, does this mean you are storing date/time values as strings? If possible use `datetime` type and if the date is not valid insert `NULL`. Why do you use `CONVERT(INT, [evt]) & 7`? Store the `INT` version of the `[evt]` field in your table to avoid having to perform this conversion every time your query runs. Also, can you avoid using `[cName] LIKE 'T%'` in your WHERE clause as `LIKE` can be slow.

Comment: It would help to see the execution plan for your statement, can you post a screen shot of it? I'll have a think to see of there might be a way of performing your query using sets, instead of all the case statements, but I have some other stuff to get on with so it might be a while before I can get back to you.

Comment: Thank you. I can wait. Beggars can't be choosers, right :)

I don't have access to the actual SQL server to answer your question. I run these queries remotely. I also don't know that much about SQL. Sorry. (That is why I am here, I guess...)

Comment: @ahmd0 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1480/discussion-between-tony-and-ahmd0)